# Show datetime in MVC causes "Templates can be used only with field access error "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a **content entity model** in my project that i created it by EF6.

```
 public partial class Content
{
    public Content()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Brief { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string MainText { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime DateOfPublish { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string SmallImageUrl { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string BigImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime DateOfExpire { get; set; }
    public string AutherUserName { get; set; }
    public long VisitVCount { get; set; }
    public string Visible { get; set; }
    public int ContentGroupId { get; set; }
    public long LikeCount { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentGroup ContentGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see i have a column **DateOfPublish** and the type of is **Datetime** .

I want to convert the date **DateOfPublish** to persian date with this function :

```
public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime? datetime)
        {
            string date;
            DateTime dt;

            if (!datetime.HasValue) return "";
            dt = datetime.Value;          
            string year = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(dt));
            string month = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
            string day = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
            if (month.Length == 1)
            {
                month = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
            }
            if (day.Length == 1)
            {
                day = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
            }
 Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt)) + "/" +

            date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
            return date;
        }
```

So i call this function in my View (**content view**) so i tried to show the date in Persian using this function.So i passed the English date to my function as you can see here:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    DateConverter objconverter = new DateConverter();
}
        <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => objconverter.ConvertToPersianToShow(item.DateOfPublish.Date ))
    </td>
```

But i got this error:

```
 Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

create a getter only property on the Content class

```
public partial class Content
{
 public string PersianToShow
 {
  get
  {
   return ConvertToPersianToShow(this.DateOfPublish);
  }
 }
}
```

and then use this in the razor view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.PersianToShow)
```

the error you get is because the MVC Input helpers that deal with expressions are limited in their input expression types (since they need to do internal caching for different types of expressions and in general it is expensive to deal with expression trees. the compile call)

the error message is a result of some of the types of expression trees supported.

Comment: I don't want to use this kind of class in my model domain.

Comment: It's the presentation layer .so i don't think so it can be a good idea ?!!

Comment: you have a view model property (DATA to be rendered) and all you're doing with a getter property on top of that is formatting it for the required rendering requirements. what do you mean by 'this kind of class'?

Comment: I mean "public partial class Content",i think this class is a part of presentation layer

Comment: so you're using your entity class as the viewmodel as well. i.e. the modelItem in @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem...    typically, there is a specific projection of the data/business classes into a view model class that caters to the UI rendering/validation only. in this case, because you're using the content class as viewmodel too, it is the same principle. you could create a viewmodel for this.. but it would be whole of Content (or whatever you need from it) + the getter.